# script to minimize / unminimize window in unity

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, unity, focus, minimize

I use Oneiric with Unity. I want to make a script that

- opens onboard if it's closed
- minimizes onboard if it's open
- unminimizes and focus onboard if it's minimized

I've tried with `wmctrl -r Onboard -b toggle,hidden`, but it doesn't do anything (I can't understand why, other options as `wmctrl -r Onboard -b toggle,maximized_horz` works fine).

I've found a more complex script [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1464311), it's made for a terminal, so I only need to replace the terminal with onboard.

However, that script doesn't work in Unity, I've tested in Oneiric and in Precise Alpha-2, it can minimize but it can't un-minimize/focus and gives this error message:

```
Wnck-WARNING **: Received a timestamp of 0; window activation may not function properly.
```

I've tested the script in gnome-shell in Oneiric and it works fine, seems to be a problem only with Unity.

Can somebody help me?

---

Hola. Uso oneiric con unity, y quiero hacer un script que

- abra onboard si está cerrado
- minimice onboard si está abierto y visible
- desminimice onboard y lo convierta en la ventana activa si está minimizado

He intentado 'wmctrl -r Onboard -b toggle,hidden' pero no hace nada (no entiendo por qué, otras opciones como 'wmctrl -r Onboard -b toggle,maximized_horz' funcionan bien).

He encontrado scripts más complicados en la red, como http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1464311 (está hecho para una terminal, solo tendría que cambiar la terminal por onboard). Sin embargo el script no funciona en unity, lo he testado en oneiric y en precise alpha-2, minimiza bien pero para desminimizar/enfocar da un error: 'Wnck-WARNING **: Received a timestamp of 0; window activation may not function properly'. He probado el script en gnome-shell en oineiric y funciona bien, así que parece un problema solo con unity.

¿Puede ayudarme alguien? Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will open onboard if its closed and kill if it is opened.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ps -A | grep onboard)
if [ "$a" = "" ]; then
onboard
else
killall onboard
fi

exit 0
```

ps.: The script can take any name except `*onboard*`.

Comment: Thank you desgua, but I prefer minimizing instead of closing (open onboard needs about 5 seconds, and unminimize is instantaneous).

Comment: I don't know why onboard isn't "obeying" wmctrl, neither xdotool when trying to minimize it... I will search for more.